# Can't see dynamicly added element in electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

i dynamicly add a element inside a div, inside a   tag, with a window.onload function.

When i go to my .html page on google chrome. I can see the element, but when i do "npm start" in my cmd, and it opens. I do NOT see the dynamicly added element.

Does anyone know how i could make it work?
Thanks.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var txt1 = "<div class=\"clickable1\">1</div>";
  var selectdiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
  $(selectdiv).append(txt1);
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Be more specific in your question. Provide the code you have tried and mention the issue

Comment: Added my script to add the element.

Comment: Any errors in the devtools console? JQuery is probably not available at that moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this to include jQuery:

```
<!-- ...my html... -->
<script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>
<script src="../my_ext_js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>

</body>
</html>
```